# Loop two dimensional array javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

I Have and array and it will contain values as bellow

```
SelfData = [
  ["Mortgage on Marrickville investment property (with C. Tebbutt)", "Commonwealth Bank"],
  ["Mortgage on Dulwich Hill investment property", "Commonwealth Bank"],
];
```

I want to show these values in a table similar to this
[image]

I tried as bellow.but it's doesn't display values as expected

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <th></th>
    <th>Nature of liability</th>
    <th>Creditor</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Self</td>
    <td>{SelfData.map((data,i)=>{
       return <tr>{data}</tr>
     })}
    </td>    
  </tr>  
</table>
```

Comment: It's not clear how you're building the HTML. Are you using React or something?

Comment: Yes.this is reactJs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like this. I used the rowspan attribute on the first element row on the table to make the Self column common. For example in this example since the array is of length 2. the rowspan will be 2 therefore the first column will stay common to all rows of the table

```js
<table>
  <tr>
    <th></th>
    <th>Nature of liability</th>
    <th>Creditor</th>
  </tr>
      {SelfData.map((data,i)=>{
       return <tr>
         {i===0 && <td rowSpan={SelfData.length}>Self</td>}
         <td>{data[0]}</td>
         <td>{data[1]}</td>
       </tr> 
     })}
</table>
```

[codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-functional-component-forked-z5g5f0)

Comment: This is working.but what if i have 3 values in the array?in my requirement,values in the inner array can be change

Comment: if you meant like 3 rows. then it should still work since rowspan takes length of SelfData array. maybe if u could give an example

Comment: I mean something like this `SelfData = [["value1","value2","value3"],["valu4", "value5"]];` . then it won't show `value3`.no of data inside the array can be change

Comment: since there are only 3 table headers. 1 empty and 2 for nature and creditor how should that be handled in that case. for example for `["value1","value2","value3"]`

Comment: in that scenario another header will come as `Activities `.If there are 3 values in a array,3 headers will display

Comment: im not quite sure how your table should look like as i cannot get an idea from the picture given. maybe you can post a new picture

Comment: Did small change in your answer and able to fixed it `{headers.map((d,j)=>return<td>data[j]}</td>})} ` . Thanks

Answer (score 1):

please try this way:

```
SelfData = [
  ["Mortgage on Marrickville investment property (with C. Tebbutt)", "Commonwealth Bank"],
  ["Mortgage on Dulwich Hill investment property", "Commonwealth Bank"],
];
  return (
    <table>
      <tr>
        <th>Nature of liability</th>
        <th>Creditor</th>
      </tr>
      {SelfData?.map((items, index) => {
        return (
          <tr>
            <td>SelfSelf</td>
            {items?.map((subItems, sIndex) => {
              return <td>{subItems}</td>;
            })}
          </tr>
        );
      })}
    </table>
```

Comment: Have you tested this to see what the result is?

Comment: Yest i have tested this code.but it's create two rows for `Self` text.but i need `Self` show once

Answer (score 1):

You can use `colspan` property in `td` elements to make the first column merge and the `vertical-align` CSS property to align the text to the top of the cell.

This would also work

```js
const SelfData = [
  [
    "Mortgage on Marrickville investment property (with C. Tebbutt)",
    "Commonwealth Bank"
  ],
  ["Mortgage on Dulwich Hill investment property", "Commonwealth Bank"]
];

function App() {
  return (
    <table>
      <tr>
        <th />
        <th style={{ textAlign: "left" }}>Nature of liability</th>
        <th style={{ textAlign: "left" }}>Creditor</th>
      </tr>
      {SelfData.map((data, i) => (
        <tr>
          {i === 0 && (
            <td rowspan="2" style={{ verticalAlign: "top" }}>
              Self
            </td>
          )}
          {data.map((d) => (
            <td>{d}</td>
          ))}
        </tr>
      ))}
    </table>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(<App/>, document.getElementById("root"))
```

```css
table,
th,
td {
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Put your data in a new table:

```
return (
        <table>
            <tr>
                <th></th>
                <th>Nature of liability</th>
                <th>Creditor</th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Self</td>
                <td>
                    <table>
                        {SelfData.map((data, i) => {
                            return <tr>
                                <td>
                                    {data[0]}
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    {data[1]}
                                </td>
                            </tr>;
                        })}
                    </table>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    );
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not *exactly* what your screenshot shows, but you could try embedding a table within a table, and then add CSS to try to mimic it as best as possible, adding a `rowspan` attribute to the first cell using the style property so that it stretches out.

```js
const data = [
  ['Mortgage on Marrickville investment property (with C. Tebbutt)', 'Commonwealth Bank'],
  ['Mortgage on Dulwich Hill investment property', 'Commonwealth Bank'],
];

function Example({ data }) {
  return (
    <table class="primary">
      <tr>
        <td style={{ rowspan: data.length }}>Self</td>
        <td>
          <table class="secondary">
            <tr class="heading">
              <td>Nature of liability</td>
              <td>Creditor</td>
            </tr>
            {data.map(row => {
              return (
                <tr>
                  <td>{row[0]}</td>
                  <td>{row[1]}</td>
                </tr>
              );
            })}
          </table>
        </td>
      </tr>  
    </table>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <Example data={data} />,
  document.getElementById('react')
);
```

```css
table { border-collapse: collapse; }
table.primary { border: 1px solid #343434; }
table.primary td:first-child { padding: 0.5em; }
table.secondary td { border: 1px solid #acacac; padding: 0.5em; }
.heading { background-color: #99FFCC; font-weight: 600; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/17.0.2/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/17.0.2/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="react"></div>
```

Comment: Oh, something went wrong, I fixed it, thank you @Andy